# Nginx Flask application

Tags: nginx, flask

I've got a flask application, and trying to configure nginx for the app.
For now only '/' page is available, another pages got 500 server error.
I'm newly in nginx, could you tell me how to fix?

Comment: How are you running the flask application? Built-in, uwsgi, gunicorn, etc...?

Comment: using uwsgi              server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/test.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/test.com.key;
    server_name ***.**.**.* test.com www.test.com;



location /{
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/var/www/www-root/data/www/test.com/test.sock;
    }

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend a `reverse proxy` configuration for something like this.

You Flask application will listen on localhost on port 8888 (for example)

And then Nginx would pass requests to that port internally

Below is a basic config for passing inbound http (port 80) requests to your flask application listening internally on port 8888

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;
    }
}
```

Serving the flask app is another question. uWSGI and Gunicorn are two great wsgi servers that flask will work great with.

EDIT: adding ssl config. (Change the paths to meet your needs)

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is ssl cerificate included on port 443, it will work with such configuration?

Comment: @admiral I've added an additional config for ssl

Comment: Now it's working thanks a lot!!!  Got another issue, my flask app cannot see environmental variables which set in .bash_profile file. Set correct way - KEY='VALUE'

Comment: If this is correct, could you select that answer as correct? As far as env vars go, I don't believe you can set them in `.bash_profile`. Try setting them at application run time to ensure they are present for your app.